# Sorting two arraylists in same order

Tags: java

I have got two arraylists :

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(5);
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(0);
numbers.add(0);
numbers.add(8);
ArrayList<String> linkers = new ArrayList<>();
linkers.add("five");
linkers.add("two");
linkers.add("zero");
linkers.add("zero");
linkers.add("eight");
```

I need to sort the numbers list in ascending order and get the linkers list sorted in the same order.

Comment: Create a dedicated object / record, representing a pair of `int` and `String`. Transform each pair to such an object. Add those pair objects to a list. Sort this list.

Comment: You could create a custom comparator that converts the strings to ints (ex: "five" -> 5) and sorts on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a one-to-one mapping of the number to their name you can do it like so.  Just sort the indices based on the list of numeric numbers.  Then use those indices to get each list's values in the proper, sorted order.  Here, I just print them to show the results.

```
 List<Integer> indices = IntStream.range(0, numbers.size()).boxed()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(numbers::get)).toList();
 
 for (int i : indices) {
     System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + " " + linkers.get(i));
 }
```

prints

```
0 zero
0 zero
2 two
5 five
8 eight
```

They could be "sorted" as follows:

```
numbers = indices.stream().map(numbers::get).toList();
linkers = indices.stream().map(linkers::get).toList();
System.out.println(numbers);
System.out.println(linkers);
```

prints

```
[0, 0, 2, 5, 8]
[zero, zero, two, five, eight]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This actually sorts the linkers list which I needed.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to group each number (`int`) with its name (`String`) in a class (Java < 15) or record (Java >= 15):

```
record NumberWithName(int value, String name) {
}
```

Then, for each pair of `int` and `String` from the two `List`s, construct a `Number`-instance and add it to a new `List numbersWithName`:

```
List<Integer> values = List.of(5, 2, 0, 0, 8);
List<String> names = List.of("five", "two", "zero", "zero", "eight");
List<NumberWithName> numbersWithName = new ArrayList<>();
for (int index = 0; index < values.size(); ++index) {
  numbersWithName.add(new NumberWithName(values.get(index), names.get(index)));
}
```

Finally, we sort this `List` with a corresponding `Comparator` and print the result:

```
numbersWithName.sort(Comparator.comparing(NumberWithName::value));
System.out.println(numbersWithName);
```

This produces the following output:

```
[NumberWithName[value=0, name=zero], NumberWithName[value=0, name=zero], NumberWithName[value=2, name=two], NumberWithName[value=5, name=five], NumberWithName[value=8, name=eight]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Parallel lists/arrays are trouble. Put corresponding elements into combined objects, then sort those.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Pair {
    public int i;
    public String s;

    public Pair(int _i, String _s) {
        i = _i;
        s = _s;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(2);
        numbers.add(0);
        numbers.add(0);
        numbers.add(8);
        ArrayList<String> linkers = new ArrayList<>();
        linkers.add("five");
        linkers.add("two");
        linkers.add("zero");
        linkers.add("zero");
        linkers.add("eight");
        
        ArrayList<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            pairs.add(new Pair(numbers.get(i), linkers.get(i)));
        }
        
        pairs.sort(new Comparator<Pair>() { 
            public int compare(Pair a, Pair b) { 
                if (a.i == b.i) return 0;
                else if (a.i < b.i) return -1;
                else return 1;
            }
        });
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(pairs.get(i).s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A TreeMap should help here where your key is the integer and the value represents the string. TreeMap is directly sorted by the key.

Comment: Can not use treemap as there are many duplicate entries.

Comment: You should try to make a object from each entry. Take care that you dont override the equals and hashCode function. Use that Object as your key and sort it by the strem API.